# How to get rid of dead bookmarks?

Tags: interface, import, workflow

I don't know how they occurred. I think I created those bookmarks and deleted the folders. I cannot click the greyed-out bookmarks. Nore, can't I use the minus symbol to the right.

[image: Bookmarks]

Comment: If you hit the down arrow below minus there should be some type of cleanup option.

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago and, of course, I tried the minus button first... which does not work on dead entries... (of course, for some reason ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the dropdown menu with the arrow button right below the minus button. There, select the *Cleanup* entry to remove the dead entries.